# Calculate before and after folder sizes when zipping

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have the code below which works fine for zipping files that meet my criteria and deleting the files, but what I want to add is for it to calculate the folder size before and after and determine the difference.  This sort of works but not very well.  Wondering if there is a better way.  Keep in mind this script typically runs for 3-4 days as it traverses our file system that is over 3TB in size.  So I want it to basically report not just what it cleaned, but how much space it reclaimed.

```
$Before = (Get-ChildItem "U:\UDS\Test" -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum).Sum

Function LogWrite
{
Param ([string]$logstring)

Add-content $Logfile -value $logstring
}

$PathToZipper="C:\Program Files\7-Zip"
$UDSFilesFolder="U:\UDS\Test"
$FileMask="*.sas7bdat"
$TimeBound="12/31/2015"
dir $UDSFilesFolder -Recurse -Filter $FileMask|where{$_.LastWriteTime -lt  $TimeBound}|foreach{
$PathToFile=Split-Path $_.FullName
$PrevSize=(Get-ChildItem $pwd.path | Measure-Object -property length -sum).Sum
$ZipProcess=Start-Process "$PathToZipper\7z.exe"  -ArgumentList " a -tzip `"$PathToFile\$($_.BaseName).zip`" `"$($_.FullName)`"" -Wait -PassThru
if (!$ZipProcess.ExitCode) {
    del $_.FullName
    LogWrite $_.FullName
}
    $AfterSize=(Get-ChildItem $pwd.path | Measure-Object -property length -sum).Sum
    $Diff = "{0:N2}" -f (($PrevSize-$AfterSize)/1MB)
    LogWrite $PrevSize, $AfterSize, $Diff
}

$After = (Get-ChildItem "U:\UDS\Test" -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum).Sum
$Calc = "{0:N2}" -f (($Before-$After)/1MB)

# *********************************************************************************************************** 
#   Now lets cleanup LogFiles older than 30 days
# *********************************************************************************************************** 

Get-ChildItem *.log | where {$_.LastWriteTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)} | remove-item -verbose


$smtpServer = "mailserver"
$smtpFrom = "from"
$smtpTo = "to"
$messageSubject = "Sample File Maintenance Script Task Completed (UDS)"
$messageBody = @"
This email is to inform you that the regularly scheduled tmp file maintenance script task completed successfully on DTWFP3.  

The script cleared up an extra $Calc MB of disk space.

Current folder size is: $($colItems = (Get-ChildItem "U:\UDS\Test" -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
"{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB")
"@


$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.Send($smtpFrom,$smtpTo,$messagesubject,$messagebody)
```

Comment: Ok, I found one of my mistakes.  I shouldn't use $pwd because this giving me the script execution directory so that explains why it was calculating 0.00 space saved.  I solved that issue, but now I'm wondering if there is a way to add up the space savings on each for loop to give a grand total of space saved?

Answer (score 0):

Disregard, I was able to solve this by creating an empty array and writing my calculations to the array in the foreach loop and then adding the array values together.  Worked like a charm